# Unable to get cache_nodes.0.address in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to fetch elastic cache node address using below , I am using count while provisioning elasticache clusters using:

```
${aws_elasticache_cluster.xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx.0.cache_nodes.0.address}
```

Getting this error:

```
* Resource 'aws_elasticache_cluster.xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx.1' does not have attribute 'cache_nodes.0.address' for variable 'aws_elasticache_cluster.xxx-xxxx-xxxxxx.1.cache_nodes.0.address'
```

when I try to fetch `id` instead of `cache_nodes.0.address`, It works, but I need elasticache node address. Any ideas on how I can get that.

## Update

Further Information:

Below snippet creates 3 ecc nodes for me

```
resource "aws_elasticache_cluster" "xxx-xxxxx-session" {
  count                = 3
  cluster_id           = "${var.pod_name}-xxx-xxxxx-${count.index}"
  engine               = "${var.ecc_engine}"
  engine_version       = "${var.ecc_engine_version}"
  node_type            = "cache.m3.xlarge"
  num_cache_nodes      = "${var.ecc_session_nodecount}"
  parameter_group_name = "${var.ecc_parameter_group_name}"
  subnet_group_name    = "${var.xxxxxxx}"
  port                 = "${var.ecc_port}"
  security_group_ids   = ["${aws_security_group.xxxxxx.id}"]
  depends_on           = ["aws_elasticache_subnet_group.xxxxxxxx"]
 }
```

Now I want to create a route53 entry for all these clusters using below, for example, for first cluster I am using the using the code below, but it does work. I worked when I wasn't using count i.e. only one cluster and a route 43 endpoint for it:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "redis-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-A0" {
  zone_id = "${lookup(var.route_53_zone_id, var.env_type)}"
  name    = "redissession0.${var.xxxxxxx}.${lookup(var.zone_record_domain, var.env_type)}"
  type    = "CNAME"
  records = ["${aws_elasticache_cluster.xxx-xxxxx-   session.0.cache_nodes.0.address}"]
  ttl     = "60"
}
```

Comment: There's not really much to go on here. Can you provide a [_complete_ example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Updated

Comment: Did you solve this?